# ¿Por qué me reconoce mi página web los caracteres sin necesidad de colocar utf-8?

Tags: html, html5

Tengo una pregunta, para que una página web te acepte acentos,ñ o algún otro caracter especial, tengo que poner la etiqueta `<meta charset="utf-8">` para que pueda reconocer los caracteres, resulta que he estado intentando colocar caracteres sin poner la etiqueta mencionada, y si me los reconoce con facilidad, alguien sabe el por qu?, o es que hay una actualización en html o se debe a mi pc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso solo funciona localmente al subir el proyecto al servidor nacen los errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al abrir un archivo local, es normal que la codificación de caracteres sea automática, esto no quiere decir que será así para siempre; ten en cuenta que al momento de subir un archivo a un servidor no tendrá la codificación de caracteres.